# Django Compressor inline removes custom attributes

Tags: python, django, django-compressor

I'm using Django compressor for Static resources. How ever while trying to compress an inline style tag, it removes custom attributes from style tag that I need for some other stuff

Code :

```
{% compress css inline %}
    <style some-custom-attribute type="text/css">
        *{
              padding:0px;
              margin:0px;
        }
    </style>
{% endcompress css %}
```

output

```
<style type="text/css">*{padding:0px;margin:0px}</style>
```

expected result

```
<style some-custom-attribute type="text/css">*{padding:0px;margin:0px}</style>
```

Comment: I have the same problem with the (not inline) `<link>` tag and `rel="preload" as="style"`

Comment: https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/690

Answer (score 1):

The solution is partially explained in https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/690:

In one of your apps (make sure it is above `compressor` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting), create a file in the template folder `compressor/css_inline.html` to override it.

In that template you can set the content to something like

```
<style type="text/css"{% if compressed.media %} media="{{ compressed.media }}"{% endif %} some-custom-attribute>{{ compressed.content|safe }}</style>
```

Note that this solution is rather hackish and will affect all compressed inline css output. You might be able to make it more dynamic by writing a custom context processor.